# UIHostingController removeChildViewController:notifyDidMove: crash on iOS 16.0 - 16.2

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I am using SwiftUI view with UIHostingController and when pushed inside the UINavigationController and pop its crashes the application. To fix this I used another UIViewController and assign the UIHostingController view to it and it does not crash anymore.

```
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    viewController.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    hostingController.view.pinToEdges()
```

This workaround works fine but I am not sure what the core issue is here.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1ae77cd90)
frame #0: 0x00000001ae77cd90 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol120141 + 92
frame #1: 0x00000001ae77cda8 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol120142 + 20
frame #2: 0x00000001af210880 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol201252 + 400
frame #3: 0x00000001adf4f06c SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol63440 + 120
frame #4: 0x00000001adf2f1b0 SwiftUI`___lldb_unnamed_symbol62835 + 40
frame #5: 0x00000001ac8c0194 UIKitCore`-[UIViewController removeChildViewController:notifyDidMove:] + 128
frame #6: 0x00000001ace866e8 UIKitCore`-[UINavigationController removeChildViewController:notifyDidMove:] + 80
frame #7: 0x00000001ac90e224 UIKitCore`-[UIViewController dealloc] + 768
frame #8: 0x00000001ac8b02c4 UIKitCore`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1392
frame #9: 0x00000001ac8af604 UIKitCore`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 96
frame #10: 0x00000001ac8af568 UIKitCore`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 172
frame #11: 0x000000022f95a4f8 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 52
frame #12: 0x00000001ac70e020 UIKitCore`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1980
frame #13: 0x00000001abbe39ec QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 500
frame #14: 0x00000001abbf70a0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 148
frame #15: 0x00000001abc085b0 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 456
frame #16: 0x00000001abc3d5ec QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 652
frame #17: 0x00000001abc268cc QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 88
frame #18: 0x00000001acc0db44 UIKitCore`_UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 52
frame #19: 0x00000001acd5b740 UIKitCore`_UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
frame #20: 0x00000001ad3a2fd0 UIKitCore`schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 172
frame #21: 0x00000001ad3a219c UIKitCore`runloopSourceCallback + 92
frame #22: 0x00000001aa621f54 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
frame #23: 0x00000001aa62e32c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
frame #24: 0x00000001aa5b2210 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
frame #25: 0x00000001aa5c7ba8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 836
frame #26: 0x00000001aa5cced4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
frame #27: 0x00000001e38ce368 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 164
frame #28: 0x00000001acaab3d0 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 888
frame #29: 0x00000001acaab034 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 340
* frame #30: 0x0000000104e310e4 Banking`main at main.swift:17:1
frame #31: 0x00000001c8c34960 dyld`start + 2528
```

Looking for any different solution or any insight on how to handle this in a better way. Thanks a lot.

```
func pinToEdges() {
    guard let superview = self.superview else { return }

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])
}
```

Comment: pinToEdges() is not system API and you didn't provide how you implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to the deallocation of the UIHostingController while the navigation stack is being manipulated.

```
 let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: 
 SwiftUIView())

let intermediateViewController = UIViewController()
intermediateViewController.addChild(hostingController)
intermediateViewController.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
intermediateViewController.view.topAnchor),
hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
intermediateViewController.view.leadingAnchor),
hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
intermediateViewController.view.trailingAnchor),
hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
intermediateViewController.view.bottomAnchor)
])
 hostingController.didMove(toParent: intermediateViewController)

 navigationController?.pushViewController(intermediateViewController, 
 animated: true)
```

Comment: deallocation will only happen when the navigation controller pop's it so while poping its crashing which doesn't make sense to me.